# ContainsPoint in Openlayers is undefined

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using Openlayers 2, this is just a mock-up code for testing a layer(POINTS) is inside the other layer(POLYGON).

```
var p = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13977549.20, 1019860.15);
for (var i = 0; i < layer_floodhazard.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = layer_floodhazard.features[i];
    if (feature.containsPoint(p)) {
        alert('Contains')
    };
}
```

When I looked at the console is says :`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and it points on the line where `containsPoint` function is.

Comment: What do you mean by that? `layer_floodhazard` is a vector layer.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you `feature` does not have the [containsPoint](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.containsPoint) Method directly.

Assuming your `layer_floodhazard.features` are [polygons](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html), you should see a `geometry` property under the feature and if the geometry is a polygon, then you should be able to see `.containsPoint` under the `.geometry` property.

Maybe you should try

```
if (feature.geometry.containsPoint(p)) {
  alert('Contains')
};
```